# Binding Data in Excel to a 2D array in C# without VSTO usage

Tags: c#, excel, com

There's some data displayed in Excel using COM interop from C#. This data is stored in a 2D array/list in C#.

Now, whenever there is a change/edit in the excel sheet I want the data stored in the data structure in C# also to change appropriately.

I would be even more happy if inserting or deleting a row in excel leads to a similar operation on this 2D data structure in C#.

This question isn't a duplicate. I cannot use a VSTO add-in to accomplish my task though Worksheet_Change event can be used.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Show us what code you have currently and whats stopping you from doing this? There isn't actually a question here.

Comment: I do not have any code as such. The only code I have is a 2d array that displays data into excel using COM-interop. I've no idea how to bind it to changes in excel.

Comment: I reopened the question, show us teh codez! You asked the [same thing over a week ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247314/binding-a-c-sharp-variable-to-an-excel-cell) - so we know you have code and that answer although marked correct doesn't resolve your problem, you need to show us why? what you want vs what you're getting. Again there is no question. Kindly read [ask]!!!